# Oracle XML query returns NULL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I need to convert XML data to field/value pair but my query for the value is returning nulls

I have an `XML` type column in Oracle that I am trying to parse to get the field/value pair. I'm not sure if the structure of the XML is the cause but I cannot extract the value.

Here is a sample of the XML data:

```
<SaleFile BRANCH_ID="ABCZ7" name="FILE20190523_BN0016_MAIN.DAT" File_Type="MAIN" id="574455888ABCYY7" type="ACCOUNT">
    <FIELD Type="ACCOUNT BALANCES AND CORRESPONDING DATES" Redact_ind="FALSE"  Name="POSTED_PMT_AMT">-673.00</FIELD>
    <FIELD Type="CONSUMER CONTACT INFORMATION" Redact_ind="FALSE" Name="SECONDARY CUSTOMER">N</FIELD>
    <FIELD Type="CONSUMER IDENTIFYING INFORMATION" Redact_ind="FALSE" Name="SECONDARY CUSTOMER NAME"></FIELD>
</SaleFile>
```

I am trying to get the posted amount returned in my query.

```sql
SELECT xt.*
FROM SALES_DATA x,
     XMLTABLE('/SaleFile/FIELD'
     PASSING x.SELLER_DATA
     COLUMNS 
       FIELD_VAL VARCHAR2(500) PATH 'FIELD'
     ) xt
```

The query runs without error but all I get back are `NULL`s.

Comment: What is the version of Oracle DB?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a different approach with `xmlSequence` and `extractValue()` with conditional in XPath expression:

```
select
    extractValue(value(e), '//FIELD[@Type=''ACCOUNT BALANCES AND CORRESPONDING DATES'']') AS "amount"
from SALES_DATA x,
    table (xmlSequence(extract(xml, '/SaleFile'))) e
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZARRA69527)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out by just trying some different codes:

SELECT xt.* FROM SALES_DATA x, 
XMLTABLE('/SaleFile/FIELD' 
PASSING x.Seller_DATA 
COLUMNS
FIELD_VAL VARCHAR2(500) PATH '/' ) xt

this gave me the list of values for each FIELD node.

Comment: You said that "...I am trying to get the posted amount...", i.e. one single value.

Answer (score 0):

You have few FIELD elements, so a filter based on the **Name="POSTED_PMT_AMT"** attribute will be helpful.

> SQL

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM SALES_DATA x,
     XMLTABLE('/SaleFile/FIELD[@Name="POSTED_PMT_AMT"]'
     PASSING x.SELLER_DATA
     COLUMNS 
       PMT_AMT NUMERIC(10,2) PATH './text()'
     ) xt
```